# linq group by hour range?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I group my data by hour like this:

```
group c by new { date = new DateTime(Date.Year, Date.Month, Date.Day, Date.Hour, 5, 0), name = c.Name } into g
```

I want to get something like this : `10.05 - 11.05`  When I debugged the code Date is returned like my expected. But data is still groupped between `10.00 - 11.00`.

I hope I can explain.What is the logic to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let offSetDate = Date.AddMinutes(-5)  //shift back so that Year,Month,Day,Hour are all that matter.
let groupKey = new {
  date = new DateTime(offSetDate.Year, offSetDate.Month, offSetDate.Day, offSetDate.Hour, 5, 0),
  name = c.Name
}
group c by groupKey into g
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var groups = dList.GroupBy(d => (d.Ticks - 5*TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute) / TimeSpan.TicksPerHour)
                .Select(g => g.ToList())
                .ToList();
```

Comment: It works but I should get my Date back ( 10:05 ). But it returns `ReadDate = {01.01.0001 00:00:00} System.DateTime` my expected for example `ReadDate = {09.11.2012 10:05:45}`

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi I don't have any idea how you use it since you didn't show your real code. But keypoint here is the use of `ticks`. Other parts are only linq tricks (don't use group's `Key`).